# Uploadify file extension filtering: remove "All Files" option in Chrome

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uploadify

I'm using uploadify with extension filters to control what files are uploaded.

I set both 
`fileExt = "*.avi;*.mpg;*.mp4;*.mov;*.wmv;";` 
and 
`fileDesc = "Videos (.avi,.mpg,.mp4,.mov,.wmv)";`

This works as expected in FF, IE7/8/9: The user is restricted to uploading files with these extensions. However, in Chrome the user is initially restricted to the file types but has the option to change the filter to "All Files" as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Open File dialog allowing user to change filter]

How can I ensure that the extension filter is adhered to?

Cheers

Comment: HiI am facing the same issue. Could you find a solution?

Comment: Afraid not, I believe I just did some validation in the onSelect callback and displayed a list of the files that weren't uploaded to the user.